# Difference between $this and simple variable in php

Tags: php, class, this

I do not understand the importance of `$this` we can access both ways i.e.

```
class student
{
private:
        $myVar;
function set_Name($tmp_myVar){
                    $this $myVar=$tmp_myVar;
                }   
}
```

and also

```
class student
{
private:
        $myVar;
function set_Name($tmp_myVar){
                     $myVar=$tmp_myVar;
                }   
}
```

then what is the logic of using `$this`

Comment: there is none, because `$this $myvar` doesn't actually mean anything. You're confused with `$this->myVar` versus `$myVar`. The first is a property of the object (which is referenced by `$this`) while the second is a local variable.

Comment: You really need to read up on using objects in PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: I'm +1 @MikeBrant, a little self-reading sure goes along way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` refers to the scope of the current object rather than the local scope of the function.

eg:

```
class Student {
  private $screenname;

  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->screenname = $name; //object scope
  }

  public function say_my_name() {
    printf("My name is %s.\n", $this->screenname);
  }

  public function say_something_else($string) {
    $screenname = $string; //local scope
    printf("My name is %s, and I say '%s'.\n", $this->screenname, $screenname);
  }
}

$obj = new Student("Betty");
$obj->say_my_name();
//Output: My name is Betty.
$obj->say_something_else('Veronica');
//Output: My name is Betty and I say 'Veronica'.
$obj->say_my_name();
//Output: My name is Betty.
```

Comment: `function say something else($string)` should read as `function say_something_else($string)` you forgot the underscores. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- need more coffee.

Comment: The "one" espresso will do the job, and then some. ;-) hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student {
    public $screenName;

    public function getScreenName() {
        return $this->screenName;
    }
}
```

The use of the **$this->** operator refers to an object that is *owned* by the calling model, which in this case is Student.

`$this` is used to call methods that belong to the owning model (class) or reference variables.

It is similar to `self`, but `self` is used for **static** methods and members. **$this** is used in an instantiated object.